# Unity Auto-Centering Text

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a spelling game for kids in Unity. I've got it so when the right letter is clicked, the letter is highlighted. I couldn't figure out how to highlight a specific char on the fly in a Text field, so I just put a highlighted version of the text behind the regular, and have the regular char disappear when clicked instead. Now, I need this text centered in the beginning, but the problem is it auto centers whenever a char disappears, misaligning the text.

[image: Screenshot of problem.]

Any ideas on how to stop getting it to auto center?

```
newWord = new StringBuilder (startWord.text);
i = 0;
if (Letter.gameObject.GetComponent<MoveLetter> ().checkIfClicked (startWord.text[i])) 
        {
            newWord [i] = ' ';
            startWord.text = newWord.ToString();
            Destroy (Letter);
            letters.Remove (Letter);
            i++;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

My answer will try to help you fix your first problem : highlighting characters.

I would advise you to not duplicate text to show the highlighted characters. Instead, use [rich text](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StyledText.html)

You can change the color of individual characters by surrounding them with the `color` tag, as follow :

```
<color=#ffff00ff>H</color><color=#ffff00ff>E</color>LP
```

This string in the `text` attribute of your `Text` component will make the `H` and `E` letters yellow, while the other letters will stay black (or whatever color you have chosen for the Text component)

---

Here is a function you can use to highlight specific letters of a given string :

```
    using System;
    // ....

    public void Foo()
    {
        // Give the indices of the letters of the string, starting at 0
        GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>().text = Highlight("HELP", "#ffff00ff", 3, 1, 2); 

       // Will output :
       // H<color=#ffff00ff>E</color><color=#ffff00ff>L</color><color=#ffff00ff>P</color>
    }

    private string Highlight(string text, string color, params int[] indices)
    {
        Array.Sort(indices);

        for (int i = indices.Length - 1 ; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if( indices[i] == text.Length - 1 )
                text = String.Format( "{0}<color={1}>{2}</color>", text.Substring(0, indices[i]), color, text[indices[i]] ) ;

            else if( indices[i] == 0 )
                text = String.Format( "<color={0}>{1}</color>{2}", color, text[indices[i]], text.Substring(1));

            else if( indices[i] < text.Length )
                text = String.Format( "{0}<color={1}>{2}</color>{3}", text.Substring(0, indices[i]), color, text[indices[i]], text.Substring(indices[i] + 1));
        }

        return text;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but isn't that using HTML? I'm using C#. Also, how would I get that to work with a dynamically changing word? It won't always be "Help".

Comment: Please, check the Unity documentation I have linked. Some tags are recognized by Unity (bold, italic, color, size, ...). I am trying to find a way to highlight the characters using this method, I will tell you if I find a solution

Comment: @MikeOD : I've made a function to help you highlighting the string using the rich text, check my updated answer ;)

Comment: @MikeOD : Have you been able to solve your problem ? Tell me if the solution I gave you does not fit your needs (or if it does!)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how Shadow works (I'm a newbie), but maybe you could try to put a Shadow component on the right letter when clicked and that way it may be easier to make it work.

EDIT:
Here, you could do it like this. Dunno how efficient it is, but I'm sure you can control it from code somehow. Add 4 components and cast a shadow in each direction
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuGGY.jpg

Answer (score 0):

@Hellium answer is the right one: using rich text is probably your best solution.

However there are two other possibilities I can think of right now:

- keep your 2 text elements (one being the background and the other being the overlay) and use a [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font): this way the background could be `"HELP"` while the overlay would be `"  LP"` (simply make sure both are the same size/alignment)
- use [TextMesh Pro](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/84126) which is now part of Unity :)

*Hope this helps,*